# How to stop incoming EmailMessage from opening duplicate cases?

Tags: service-cloud-console, case-object, email2case

We have about 15 email addresses that are set up as email-to-case address that folks can use to create a case with our customer service team.  The problem that we've been running into more and more lately is that if a customer sends a single email to more than one of these addresses, it creates duplicate cases in the queue and sometimes leads to wasted resources as multiple CS agents respond to the same problem in separate threads.

So far I have not been able to find a good way of mitigating this.  I was thinking of using a `before insert` trigger on email messages to check if I am inserting duplicates and assigning them both to the same case.  But rather than reduce duplicates this has ended up creating cases with no related Email Messages, which is obviously not ideal.

Has anyone found a good way of handling these duplicate cases with email-to-case?